# SOAP header: why authenticate in the header and not the body?

Tags: c#, web-services, api, authentication, soap

SOAP header: why authenticate in the header and not the body?

whats the differences between putting the user's credentials (username/password) in the header vs the user's credentials (username/password) in the body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, authenticating in the SOAP Header can allow a single piece of code to authenticate all requests into the SOAP WS without knowing the actual contents of the SOAP Envelope. This can greatly reduce the amount of code you need to authenticate your services.

If you don't put it in the header, you'll need to do the authentication at the time of processing the Service, which is more expensive than NOT processing the service at all if authentication fails

for example, check out [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/223433/Web-Services/java/Intercepting-XML-Servlet-Filter) and [here](http://www.developer.com/security/article.php/3467801/Securing-J2EE-Applications-with-a-Servlet-Filter.htm)

Comment: Well, it would usually go into some sort of a filter BEFORE it gets to your handler. This is really easy to do w/ Servlets. A Filter would intercept the request before it goes to the handler. The filter would then get the headers, figure out the authentication, and if not correct, would NOT pass the request to the handler. This way, the handler is only being activated when the request is valid.

Comment: hmm you still have to check the credientials again within the methods.

Comment: you MAY for Authorization, but not for Authentication. These are different concerns. You can also use the Filter to insert items into the Session, this way you won't have to go back to DB for user info. Again, you want to do things that are expensive once.

Answer (score 2):

SOAP follows a format which defines the `Body` as the message. The `Header` is open ended to some degree and can be used for varying reasons by varying frameworks, whereas the `Body` has a sole purpose, transmitting the message.